# Avoid to repeat require statements in nodejs modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, module

Currently I'm develloping an app in Express and I've created several services which are modules called from a single `index.js` file:

```
"use strict";

const MAX_TEXT_LENGTH = 100;

var mysql    = require('mysql')
  , _        = require('underscore')
  , Q        = require('q')
  , moment   = require('moment')
  , env      = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'

module.exports.module1     = require('./module1');
module.exports.module2     = require('./module2');
module.exports.moduleN     = require('./moduleN');
```

Thanks to this structure I can now call a single time to `var Services = require('./services')` and I've access to all services.

The problem is that the modules, constants and "global" vars used in this file aren't available in the modules so I have to call them many times.

I've also tried to name vars as `let` but this doesn't work.

Is there any way to be able to define modules and variables in this `index.js` file and use them inside modules?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your modules, instead of returning only one simple value, return an object where each key is one the variables that you want to export. Something like this.

```
var myModuule = {
  varIWantToExport: 1,
  methodIWantToExport: function() { return "Hello world!";}
}
module.exports = myModule;
```

And then, when you require it in other modules, you can do something like this:

```
var myModule = require("./my-module");
var myMethod = myModule.methodIWantToExport
var myVar = myModule.varIWantToExport;
```

Obviously this only applies to your modules. If you are trying to use some variables/methods that are not publicly exposed in a module, maybe you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Thanks dlopez! But my case is the opposite, the question is if it is possible to use, let's say, "global vars" defined outside a module. Declaring them as `vars` is not valid.

Comment: In that case what you can do is that your module exports a function, that requieres some args. That args will be your "global vars" that comes from outside the module. Then when you require your module you have to do something like this. `var myModule = require("./my-module")(global1, global2, ...)

I think that it is the only that we can do, because the modules in fact are done to be completely isolated from the outside of itself.